# AngularJs : json parsing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a Json file and display photos on web using angularjs.
But Json data is not getting parsed.

This is my js :

```
 var myApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['angularGrid']);

    myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
    ]);

    myApp.service('imageService',['$q','$http',function($q,$http,$scope){
        this.loadImages = function(){
            return $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vedant1811/ebc4effaeeb2d4524460164a3524d003/raw/ecfa9855867c1b51dad52936cfe4b83a3447ea7a/example_model_response.json");
        };
    }])
    .controller('demo', ['$scope','imageService', 'angularGridInstance', function ($scope,imageService,angularGridInstance) {
       imageService.loadImages().then(function(data){
            data.photos.forEach(function(obj){
                var desc = obj.description,
                    width = desc.match(/width="(.*?)"/)[1],
                    height = desc.match(/height="(.*?)"/)[1];
                obj.actualHeight  = height;
                obj.actualWidth = width;
            });

           $scope.pics = data.photos;
        });;
    }]);
```

Here's a part of my Json File:

```
{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "username",
        "location": "locationname",
        "sex": "female",
        "height": 134,
        "bio": "Actress and Model",
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 113,
                "description": "",
                "width": 184,
                "height": 274,
                "position": null,
                "icon": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/icon/b886c18cccd174f06b5d9b89c73aa937.jpeg?1460810525",
                "medium": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/medium/b886c18cccd174f06b5d9b89c73aa937.jpeg?1460810525",
                "large": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/large/b886c18cccd174f06b5d9b89c73aa937.jpeg?1460810525",
                "xlarge": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/xlarge/b886c18cccd174f06b5d9b89c73aa937.jpeg?1460810525"
            },
            {
                "id": 112,
                "description": "",
                "width": 160,
                "height": 200,
                "position": null,
                "icon": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/icon/c9b59672a96087640a69b4d8c7cca00b.jpeg?1460810626",
                "medium": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/medium/c9b59672a96087640a69b4d8c7cca00b.jpeg?1460810626",
                "large": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/large/c9b59672a96087640a69b4d8c7cca00b.jpeg?1460810626",
                "xlarge": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/voggle-paperclip-production/production/photoable/xlarge/c9b59672a96087640a69b4d8c7cca00b.jpeg?1460810626"
            },
```

Here's my HTml body :

```
    <body class="" data-ng-controller="demo">
        <ul class="dynamic-grid" angular-grid="pics" grid-width="300" gutter-size="10" angular-grid-id="gallery" refresh-on-img-load="false" >
            <li data-ng-repeat="pic in pics" class="grid" data-ng-clock>
                <img src="{{pic.medium}}" class="grid-img" data-actual-width = "{{pic.actualWidth}}"  data-actual-height="{{pic.actualHeight}}" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Please anyone can help?

Comment: what does "Json data is not getting parsed" mean, exactly? if you place a few `console.log` statements inside your `.then` callback, do you not have the data you expect?

Comment: Try using the `Network` tab on your browser's developer console to make sure that what you are receiving what you think you are. The response might be simply a string and not an object as you think. Also it would help if you explained what is the exact error or issue.

Comment: I want to display images of medium size as in json file. But nothing is displayed ! @dearn44

Comment: Try my suggestion and tell us the actual response that comes from your call in `imageService.loadImages()`. Use the developer console or add another function for the case that your promise does not get resolved.

Comment: your code has multiple issues.  After fixing the code to correct the issues with `data` vs `data.data`, the `.then` function still fails, specifically because your code is looking for a match to a string `desc` that is `""` and won't have any matches found.  You should take a bit of time to learn to debug your code a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not properly handling the objects so that you were getting undefined exceptions. 2nd is you need data.data.photos.

```
.controller('demo', ['$scope','imageService', function ($scope,imageService) {
   imageService.loadImages().then(function(data){
        data.data.photos.forEach(function(obj){
           var desc = obj.description;
           width = null;
           height = null;
           if(desc){
                width = desc.match(/width="(.*?)"/)[1],
                height = desc.match(/height="(.*?)"/)[1];
           }
            obj.actualHeight  = height;
            obj.actualWidth = width;
        });
       $scope.pics = data.data.photos;
    });
}]);
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5080/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change all `data.photos` to `data.data.photos`

The response object has these properties:

data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

You can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: An explanation why would help OP understand better

Comment: It could also be `d.photos`, but trying randomly until you get it is not the correct way of solving his issue.

Comment: @dearn44 This answer is because OP's `data` is actually a `$http` response object that among other properties include the `data` property. It is not a guess

Comment: Nope. data.data.photos will not work ..! I guess raw github url is prevented in ajax call

Comment: @Abhishek you would find that out in your error handling but you haven't implemented any.

Answer (score 1):

No need to put those forEach and in addition change `data.photos` to `data.data.photos` like as per [E. Abrakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37677896/1575570) answer, take a look at the following stuff

```js
var myApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
    ]);

    myApp.service('imageService',['$q','$http',function($q,$http,$scope){
        this.loadImages = function(){
            return $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vedant1811/ebc4effaeeb2d4524460164a3524d003/raw/ecfa9855867c1b51dad52936cfe4b83a3447ea7a/example_model_response.json");
        };
    }])
    .controller('demo', ['$scope','imageService', function ($scope,imageService) {
       imageService.loadImages().then(function(data){
           $scope.pics = data.data.photos;
        });
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="demo">
  <ul class="dynamic-grid" angular-grid="pics" grid-width="300" gutter-size="10" angular-grid-id="gallery" refresh-on-img-load="false">
    <li data-ng-repeat="pic in pics" class="grid" data-ng-clock>
      <img src="{{pic.medium}}" class="grid-img" data-actual-width="{{pic.actualWidth}}" data-actual-height="{{pic.actualHeight}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes.. I guess /raw/ github url are restricted from being used in ajax calls

Comment: Hmm... Thanks a lot @Nidish .. :)